# How to open toc automatically when open a .ipynb file in jupyterlab?

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, tableofcontents

When I open a file in jupyterlab. The left sidebar will disappear the file browser.
[file browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcXAC.png)

But I want to open the toc.
I try to write a javascript to simulate click the toc button in sidebar, but it doesn't work.
There are any configuration or script can open toc?

Comment: You can move the TOC to the right sidebar by right-clicking on the item in sidebar and clicking "Switch Sidebar Side".

Answer (score 0):

JupyterLab 4.0 will include `toc:show-panel` command, and in earlier versions you can activate ToC using [`activateById()`](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/interfaces/application.jupyterfrontend.ishell.html#activatebyid) method from `JupyterFrontEnd.IShell` interface using `table-of-contents` identifier.

You can try it out on [jupyterlab-plugin-playground](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-plugin-playground) with the following code:

```js
import { JupyterFrontEnd, JupyterFrontEndPlugin } from '@jupyterlab/application';
import { NotebookPanel, INotebookTracker } from '@jupyterlab/notebook';


const plugin: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
  id: 'toc-show:plugin',
  autoStart: true,
  requires: [INotebookTracker],
  activate: (app: JupyterFrontEnd, notebookTracker: INotebookTracker) => {
    alert('TOC-show extension activated!'); // you can remove this
    notebookTracker.currentChanged.connect((_: any, notebookPanel: NotebookPanel | null) => {
      if (notebookPanel) {
        // JupyterLab 3.x:
        app.shell.activateById('table-of-contents');
        // JupyterLab 4.0+:
        // app.commands.execute('toc:show-panel');
      }
    });
  },
};

export default plugin;
```

For packaging/installing it as a permanent extension you can follow the [JupyterLab extension tutorial](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_tutorial.htm).

In future it might be possible to recreate this functionality from [ipylab](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab) but currently it does not implement signal handlind.